# How to automatically create a user account when someone donates?

Tags: civicontribute, user-account, user-dashboard

My idea is something like this:

1. When someone gives a donation, an account with specific permission gets created.
2. User gets notification of the account creation via the contribution receipt or a separate email
3. When they login, it should redirect them to user dashboard

Is this something possible to achieve? I am on drupal 7. CiviCRM 5.20

Any alternative idea or suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible by using a profile - see the 'Advanced Settings' of the profile used in the contribution page and you'll see (towards the bottom) the settings re creating a drupal account.  When they have set a password and logged in to Civi the dashboard is the default.